# Is there a way to have Dependency Injection and an Extension method interact?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, extension-methods

I have a method in my NuGet package library that looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetLogoutUrl(HttpContext httpContext, string encodedUserJwt, string relativeRedirectUrl)
{
    var redirectUrl = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}/{relativeRedirectUrl}";
    var logoutUrlParameters = $"id_token_hint={encodedUserJwt}&post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUrl}";
    var logoutUrl = $"{await DiscoveryDocument.GetLogoutEndpoint()}?{logoutUrlParameters}";
    return logoutUrl;
}
```

I would really like to make it an extension method of `HttpContext` so the users of my NuGet can call it like this: `HttpContext.GetLogoutUrl(encodedUserJwt, "Home");`

But the problem with that is that this method uses `DiscoveryDocument` that is injected into the class where this method currently resides.  I have been trying to think of a way I could get the nice syntax of an extension method, but still be able to get the `DiscoveryDocument` from dependency injection while not breaking so many best practices that I can't sleep at night.

**Is there a way in C# to have an extension method and still connect to a dependency injected object?**

NOTE: I don't want to make the developers that use my NuGet to have to pass in an instance of `DiscoveryDocument`.  For the architecture of my NuGet that would be worse than just having `GetLogoutUrl` not be an extension method.

Comment: Extension method -> static class -> no DI :)

Comment: Why *not* require it as a parameter? `DiscoveryDocument` is effectively an input to that method, even if it's by implicit `this.`. It's a dependency.

Comment: @madreflection - While public, it is at a deeper level than what I want my users to have to interact with.  As I said, it will be better to keep it in the class it is in.  (The class it is in is at a "medium" level where as `DiscoveryDocument` is at a "Low" level.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741876/how-to-avoid-service-locator-in-net-extension-methods

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282223/implementing-dependency-injection-static-methods

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325438/how-to-inject-dependency-to-static-class (duplicate?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service locator via

```
IServiceProvider HttpContext.RequestServices { get }
```

will have to be used since this is a static call , which does not usually play well with DI since it is usually centered around instances.

The potential extension method would end up looking something like this

```
public static async Task<string> GetLogoutUrl(this HttpContext httpContext, 
    string encodedUserJwt, string relativeRedirectUrl) {
    var redirectUrl = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}/{relativeRedirectUrl}";
    var logoutUrlParameters = $"id_token_hint={encodedUserJwt}&post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUrl}";

    var DiscoveryDocument = httpContext.RequestServices
        .GetRequiredService<DiscoveryDocumentTypeHere>();

    var logoutUrl = $"{await DiscoveryDocument.GetLogoutEndpoint()}?{logoutUrlParameters}";
    return logoutUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I get that Service Locator is an anti-pattern, but how does this not play well with DI?  (If I go this way, I need to know what problems in my DI system I may see.)

Comment: None provided you are the one registering the known types in the composition root. I assume your Nuget has some configuration extension that adds all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: My NuGet does add the dependencies.  I had considered using a singleton to dependency inject into, and then accessing the singleton from the static extension method.  I think this is much cleaner. Though still using an anti-pattern, I think the trade off may be worth it.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: the anti-pattern in this scope is that the implementation needs DI types registered and configured for it's usability.  Before you commit to this pattern, do a unit test of your extension method.